# Is Linux or Windows better for learning Network Administration?

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I am currently studying for my CCNA, and while the textbook I have uses Windows throughout, is it better to learn it through Windows or Linux for Enterprise Network Administration?

(***By "better" I mean, which is more resourceful/lucrative/widely-used?)***

Comment: The actual answer is that a network will usually have many different devices and operating systems on those devices. It isn't one or the other, the best way to learn is by learning how to do things in both OSes. Unfortunately, most people who really do that become Linux fanatics and begin to dislike Windows (which is why I suspect that the answers you have so far don't mention AD; which is essential knowledge for any sys admin today). BTW, this question probably deserves a close vote for being opinion based.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand both would be the best, I am just wondering based on peoples experiences with where the industry might be moving. Also, whether or not Linux includes all of the Windows Network Admin tools with a little extra, or vice versa. As far as AD goes, I should probably mention I already have some enterprise level experience with AD, so if that's all Windows has to offer as extra I can already maneuver the OS enough on a sys admin lvl. (Trying to talk more Network Admin role dealing with routers hubs switches etc.) How do I do a close vote? Relatively new here.

Comment: @oxy looking at all the answers here, it seems that they are relatively similar. How did you decide which one was the correct one ?

Comment: @Bongo Honestly because I have to pick just one. David's seemed to be the most relevant to me personally while all answers were correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either "it depends" or "both".

If you are heading into an industry that is very Windows centric or Linux centric then concentrate on that side, otherwise you are likely to encounter both and should understand at least the basics of both thoroughly. Which ever one you concentrate on, you will at some point have to interact with the other.

With regard to Linux being easier to play with (due to being freely available), you can run Windows Server 2012 Eval Edition in VMs pretty easily, though this may be against the EULA so do ready that text in detail before proceeding. You'll need to reinstall after six months when the evaluation license expires, and again this may be against the EULA, but other you have access to everything so you can setup in your private set of VMs a DC (or two or more), a couple of servers & clients, and play to your hearts content in order to learn what is going on. If you are following an official course you may also be eligible for educational licensing through your institution. Other options for practising administration of features that do not require higher editions of Windows is to use some of the cheap VPS providers who are offering Windows license rental with their product these days.

With regard to the EULA issues: the Microsoft Press study/revision book for exam 70-463 documents using evaluation editions in this manner for both Windows and SQL Server, so while it might not be officially supported it does seem to be an accepted approach to learning. Though I'm no lawyer so take this with a truck load of salt.

Comment: So with that out of the way, would you suggest CentOS, Fedora, or Debian? I'd include Kali but that seems to be more strictly geared towards pentesting...

Comment: Just pick one, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @David Spillett I am not a legal expert but it seems that your advice is with regards to many EULAs illegal. You are not allowed to reinstall an Eval Edition time after time after time. Is microsoft here an exemption ?

Comment: @Bongo: Fair point, I'll update the text accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

I think Linux is much better to learn network administration. If you configure Linux networks, you have to know what you are doing, otherwise you won't get it work.
With Windows you have a working network soon, but you don't know what you have done....

Just my two cent

Comment: Excellent point. And if you know what you're doing and what's going on under the hood, it'll be easier to configure new systems in the same way - as opposed to having memorized which buttons to click in a specific gui (Windows).

Comment: That's what I was hoping you all would say. I've always wanted to get into Linux and now u gave a reason to. I want to know what's going on under the hood rather since I'd be using a GUI iOS simulator regardless for CCNA which are available on both OS's.

Comment: Indeed. I've always felt that Microsoft focuses on making common tasks easy, at the cost of making less common tasks much harder.

Answer (score 3):

Linux is more widely used I'd say. Especially if you want to go big. Network is often bundled with Servers - and Servers usually run some kind of Linux.

*IMHO* Linux is at least better in anything with developing because it allows you to tinker. - But that's just IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I think Linux is the better way to learn Network Administration. Because with linux there are several tools which are even used in large deployments and also a very good documentation of each of tools. There are also particular Linux distributions which come preloaded with Network Administration tools.